# How to create a variable that adds values of a certain variable by group?

Tags: analytics, spss

I have an SPSS data set that looks like the one below. How can I compute the basket size based on the invoice no (i.e. the total number of items per invoice)? The cases are listed product wise.

```
Item Code | Description | Invoice No | Invoice Qty

1234      | Bread       |12345678    | 2

1543      | Bun         |12345678    | 3

1234      | Bread       |98765432    | 6
```

So the end result should be:

```
Item Code | Description | Invoice No | Invoice Qty | Basket Size

1234      | Bread       |12345678    | 2           | 5

1543      | Bun         |12345678    | 3           | 5

1234      | Bread       |98765432    | 6           | 6
```

Comment: you want to keep the item codes and descriptions, even though you're aggregating up to the invoice level?  Looks like you might need to do an aggregate and then a merge...

Answer (score 1):

Aggregating using invoice as the break variable is the way to go.

```
aggregate /break = InvoiceNo /BasketSize = sum(InvoiceQty).
```

Gives:

```
ItemCode Description InvoiceNo InvoiceQty BasketSize 

    1234 Bread        12345678         2       5.00 
    1543 Bun          12345678         3       5.00 
    1234 Bread        98765432         6       6.00
```